# receiving a nil:NilClass error for a non nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So here is the code that it's making me crazy:

```
  puts document.nil?  # print False

  if document.nil?  # shouldn't enter since document.nil? is false
    begin
      document = conect_documents.find("123")
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      return false
    end
  end

  attrs = document.attributes.key?('import')  # thows  undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass
```

what I'm missing here?

EDIT:
full stack-trace

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass
 # ./path/permission.rb:217:in `edit?'
 # ./path/documents_controller.rb:67:in `update'
 # ./spec/login_spec_helper.rb:11:in `block in process'
 # ./spec/login_spec_helper.rb:32:in `catch'
 # ./spec/login_spec_helper.rb:32:in `_catch_warden'
 # ./spec/login_spec_helper.rb:11:in `process'
 # ./path/documents_controller_spec.rb:468:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: What does the full stack trace look like?

Comment: Again, use your debugger. Step through the code. We can't do that for you, and we can't help you here if you can't produce a MCVE.

Comment: @user229044 I honestly don't know which part you are confused about, please stop closing questions without properly reading them, if I use a binding.pry, it shows that document.nil? is False, but it's still executing the code inside the if method

Comment: You wall off *part* of your code against a `nil` `document`, but then you go and do `document.attributes` like everything is fine, which it might not be. Are you sure that `find` is throwing an exception on a miss?

Comment: PSA: You can often collapse code like this with `document ||= ...` and `document&.attributes...`

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full controller action function from `def` to `end`. Probably what's happening is in your actual code (and trust me, I get it - translating from codebase to SO is non-trivial) doesn't stop execution in the rescue. IMHO what you *should* do is catch RecordNotFound in a controller `rescue_from`, rather than inside the action - and that's if Rails doesn't already automagically convert RNF to what you'd want as a response anyway.

Comment: You're probably using Rails if you're using ActiveRecord. It's also likely that you have a typo in `conect`.

Comment: Your stack trace is telling you that there's a problem with `NoMethodError: undefined method \`attributes' for nil:NilClass` when called on *document*.  Your flow logic isn't preventing #attributes from being called on whatever *document* is supposed to hold because it's `nil`. There are lots of ways to fix that, but we can't tell you why it's nil because there isn't enough context or debugging in your question. I've provided an answer to help with that, but you'll need to open a new, related question rather than just updating this one if you find a more specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Simplify Code to Log and Propagate Exceptions

You didn't provide a reproducible example in your original question. However, you seem to be making a number of assumptions about how your actual control flow works and the objects involved that likely aren't true. These assumptions include, but are possibly not limited to:

1. #nil? means "not empty"
2. calling #conect_documents (where's the second `n` in "connect"?) never returns nil or an empty object
3. *documents* always holds an object that can #respond_to?(:attributes)
4. `documents.attributes` always returns an object such as a Hash or Struct that can #respond_to?(:key?)
5. you are rescuing the right exception
6. you're in a context you can `return` from

None of these things are provably true from your posted example, and the stack trace clearly shows that `conect_documents` (which may be a typo) is returning nil or another object that doesn't have an #attributes method, which is why it's raising an exception.

The following example may not be fully valid for your application, but will illustrate how to use interim variables and break longer method chains to debug this more effectively, and to inspect other exceptions you may not be examining properly.

```rb
# let errors get raised rather than peppering safe
# navigators or if/thens so you can figure out what's
# actually wrong
def foo document=nil
  document = connect_documents.find(123) if document.blank?
  attrs = document.attributes
  attrs.key? "import"

# this is all you need to handle missing IDs;
# don't capture the exception object if you
# have no use for it
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  false

# rescue other exceptions for debugging, then re-raise
rescue => e
  # find out what's really being raised; use $stderr.puts if
  # you're not using the Rails logger for some unknown reason
  logger.error "debugging exception #{e.class}: #{e.message}"

  # document may be nil, empty, or not respond to #attributes;
  # find out what the document object actually is
  logger.debug "document: #{document.inspect}"

  # re-raise the original exception
  raise e
end
```

Once you've isolated your bug, you can remove the second rescue clause. However, you may still want to refactor so that you're validating in your Document model rather than cluttering up DocumentController methods with things you're finding hard to debug.